# alert when two text boxes have text entered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to display an alert box to the user of a webpage that has a number of text boxes.

This alert would depend on the values entered in two (or more) text boxes.

How can I bind or otherwise determine when the user has entered text into all textboxes in order to determine when to show an alert.

Comment: Check the values of the required checkboxes on the `keypress` event of each.

Comment: Try using the `blur` event on each one to check the contents of the others when you leave a textbox. The `length` of their `val` should be `> 0` or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have 4 `textarea` fields. You could try something like this:

```
var txtCount = 0;

$("textarea").on("blur", function() {
    $("textarea").each(function() {
        if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
            txtCount++;
        }

    }

if (txtCount == 4) { //do stuff }

});
```

This checks on all of the `textarea`s whenever one loses focus (`blur` event). jQuery loops through each `textarea` and checks the length of its contents. If the value is greater than zero (meaning something is in it), a counting variable increments. If that variable hits the total number of `textarea`s, you know there is content in each.